# Sql Server 2008 Backup in External Hard Disk Drive

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server database on an external hard disk drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/48958/sql-server-database-on-an-external-hard-disk-drive)

I want to take the backup of our companys SQL Server 2008 databalse in an External Drive which is hosted in Windows 2008 server. But when I try to schedule the backup thru maintainance window of Sql Server Management Studio, my external device drive is not displayed. How can I access this device thru mainitainance window and take the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is directly connected then just enter the drive letter into the destination box. If it is a network drive then you need to enable sharing and specify the UNC path in the destination box. SSMS just seems to show local drives.

Comment: We are using Windows 2008 Server. Its not accepting the Drive letter when I tried to access the same.

Comment: Yes but is it a local drive or a share?